# How to set selected text or value of a dropdown using jquery in a dynamically filled dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have created drop down dynamically but not able to change its value at run-time using jquery or java-script.

I want to set selected value or selected text in drop down.

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML and the JS that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set value

```
$("#dropdown").val(yourValue);
```

To get Value

```
var getValue = $("#dropdown").val();
```

Comment: It does not works.. on keeping value in alert it gives undefined..
value is not set using above syntax..

Comment: var getValue = $("#dropdown").val().   This line requires the # symbol to select the id

Comment: I have put # symbol too but didnt work.. It might be due to dropdown is dynamically filled up..